# Facing CORS error even after adding CORS options on React/Node/Passport for Google Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, passport-google-oauth

I am building a simple app with React as frontend and Node/Express/MongoDB as backend. I am authenticating user using Passport. Local authentication is working, as well as Google authentication.

I just seem to not able to load the google login page through the app. I am getting CORS error. I have shared the error below.

On React Login page:

```js
const onClick = async () => {
    await Axios.get('/auth/google');
  };
```

Proxy Middleware:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/auth', { target: 'http://localhost:4000' }));
};
```

Node Server.js:
`app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));`

routes/auth file:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};

router.get(
  '/google',
  cors(corsOptions),
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email'],
  }),
);

router.get('/google/redirect',cors(corsOptions), passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

passportconfig.js:

```js
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: ClientID,
        clientSecret: ClientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
        proxy: true,
      },
      (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // passport callback function
        //check if user already exists in our db with the given profile ID
        User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then((currentUser) => {
          if (currentUser) {
            //if we already have a record with the given profile ID
            done(null, currentUser);
          } else {
            //if not, create a new user
            new User({
              googleId: profile.id,
            })
              .save()
              .then((newUser) => {
                done(null, newUser);
              });
          }
        });
      },
    ),
  );
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fredirect&scope=profile%20email&client_id=<clientID>.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

If I click on the above XMLHttpRequest link, I am able to authenticate and an account is created on my DB with googleID.

I have tried different options suggested throughout internet, but none of them is working for me. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#usage), try removing the `corsOptions` entirely and just use the `cors()` function in your express middle-ware before any router is declared. Like so:

`app.use(cors());`

Let me know if this works.